# Addressable LEDs using SM16704

Tags: arduino-nano, led-strip

I've been asked to interface with some LED strips that use SM16704 pixel chips.

A site search here doesn't show any mentions of this chip, so I wonder if anyone knows if they're compatible with the more common ones like WS281x and can be addressed using FastLED or other library?

Edit:

**[Here's](http://www.jad-leds.com/web/userfiles/download/SM16704PB-Datasheet.pdf)** the datasheet for the -PB version of the chip. I can't find one for a plain 16704 but I don't think the protocol is any different.

Comment: the timing is quite different ... you could rewrite the library

Answer (score -1):

The best data I can find says that this chip / protocol is compatible with the WS2813 and should require only a minor tweak, if any.